# Getting the Most Recent Posts from Multiple Categories

Tags: categories, loop, pages

I've got a page (page, not post) that near the bottom of the page I want to get the most recent 15 posts from a set of categories. I'm new to doing this and thought I was doing it correctly. The div (.article-item) repeats out 15 times as expected, but none of the specific post info is coming through.

```
<?php 

   $catIDs = array(2,4,5,6,7,16);

   $args = array(
   'numberposts'     => 15,
   'category__in'    => $catIDs,
   'orderby'         => 'post_date',
   'order'           => 'DESC',
   'post_status'     => 'publish' );

   $posts_array = get_posts( $args );

?>

<div class="left-side">
   <div class="article-grid group">
      <?php foreach ($posts_array as $postd): ?>

      <div class="col2 article-item <?php echo $postd->name; ?>-article">
         <div class="article-item-content">
            <p>
               <span class="category">
                  <?php echo $postd->name; ?>:
               </span> 
               00/00/00
            </p>

            <h2><?php echo the_title(); ?></h2>
            <div class="article-link">
               <a href="<?php get_the_permalink(); ?>">READ MORE</a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.article-item -->

      <?php endforeach; ?>
</div><!-- /.article-grid -->
```

As you can see, I've tried grabbing things off of the array (`postd->name;`) as well as the `get_the_whatever` type functions. I'm think it has to do with the fact that I'm in a page template, rather than a post/post template, but am a little over my head. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following for multiple post types, just replace `foo` and `bar` with your own post types:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => array( 'foo', 'bar' ),
            'orderby'         => 'post_date',
            // other parameters as needed
            );

    $q = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ($q->have_posts()) : while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post(); 
    // do stuff

    endwhile;
endif;
```